# Transparent Image Using GraphicsMagick

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I am using GraphicsMagick and I am trying to create a 200px by 200px transparent TIF image. However, the resulting image, when opened in Photoshop, has a black background. If I use ImageMagick, it works.

The following ImageMagick command creates a transparent image (when opened in Photoshop)

```
magick convert -size 200x200 xc:transparent transparent1.tif
```

But, the same GraphicsMagic command creates a black image (when opened in Photoshop)

```
gm convert -size 200x200 xc:transparent transparent2.tif
```

I am at a loss. I would like to use GraphicsMagic because the Node API has streaming support and provides some other nice features.

Comment: I really do not know GM, but know IM well. GM is an old offshoot of imagemagick that has not been upgraded with all the ImageMagick newer features. So, just a guess, but in ImageMagick "none" is the same as "transparent". So try `gm convert -size 200x200 xc:none transparent2.tif`. Does that work?

Comment: Taking an educated guess with more expertise using IM and not so much GM, I would probably try adding "-background transparent" (or "-background none") before creating the "xc:transparent" canvas.

Comment: @fmw42 Your example still produced a black image when opened in Photoshop. I decided to use ImageMagick through GraphicsMagick's API. It allows me to use IM directly while still getting other features, such as streaming.

Comment: @GeeMack Thanks, but still no luck. I am leaving the question open, even though I found a workaround. The issue is still there.

Comment: Perhaps you need to upgrade your version of GM. But would it not be better to switch to  IM, since it is much more advanced than GM.